# Forcing https in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I try to force https in .htaccess as such:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It works when I try `www.example.com`, but if I try something like `www.example.com/contact-us`, it is still with `http`. Is there something wrong with my `.htaccess`?

Note I do not have access to the cPanel (hosted on crazydomain) nor Wordpress admin. So upload my `.htaccess` is my only option.

Answer (score 1):

All rules are applied **in order.** You have rules before the rule handling HTTPS redirects, and those rules all end with `[L]`, meaning that rule evaluation will stop there.

Put your HTTPS redirect first before caring about more detailed pages and files.